# POST API via PHP script

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, guzzle, gravity-forms-plugin

Is there any specific way as to how to POST API calls to triggering a PHP script?

Base URL: http://api.example.com/send/msg.php

Parameters: user, pass, src, dst

What I wish to achieve is collect user, pass, src and dst via a frontend form (Gravity Forms on Wordpress); pass those variables(using [gform_after_submission hook](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_after_submission/#2-send-entry-data-to-third-party)) to the newly constructed PHP script which would ultimately do a POST to the API.

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

EDIT: Following is the source for the PHP which receives values from the form after it is submitted.
What I wish to accomplish is that link the following PHP to the API as mentioned above and pass on the data.

```
<?php
    'src' => $_POST[src"], 
    'dst' =>  $_POST["dst"], 
    'text' => $_POST["text"], 
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean sending the data or processing the data?

Comment: Do you mean posting from the front-end via ajax?

Comment: @Manngo Gravity Forms will collect the data, pass on the data using gform_after_submission hook to a php which would further process the collection such as adding or deleting phrases before and after 'user' to prepare it before posting them to the API. Once everything is in place fire the API. I have already completed the collection of variables step from the frontend form, but stuck as to how to further process the collected variable before sending it to API.

Comment: @JasonJoslin Yes, but before posting I wish to collect the the variables from the frontend ajax form into a new php to further process the collected variable before firing it off using the API. The php must get its variables using the POST from the form (which I've already able to do using 'dst' =>  $_POST["dst"] and similarly for the other variables) but I'm stuck as to how should I trigger the API and pass on the processed collected variables.

Comment: Regarding your edit, shouldn’t that be inside an array or something?